# Select address ignoring blank columns

Tags: sql, ingres

Ingres DB, property data as below

```
addr1
addr2
addr3
addr4
postcode
```

Some address are short and so have no values in addr3 or addr4. E.g.

```
addr1 : 14 Random Street
addr2 : City
addr3: 
addr4: 
postcode : LT1 5GH
```

The postcode is always populated.

How can I select the address elements in contiguous fields using SQL?

So the output I want would be as below

```
14 Random Street, City, LT1 5GH
Flat 5, 15 Random Street, District, London, E35 5FG
67 Whatever Crescent, Lovely Street, Eastwich, LH6 &GH
```

Comment: Triple self left join?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean, can you provide an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this using a `case` expression.

```
case when addr1<> '' and addr1 is not null then addr1 +',' else '' end +
case when addr2<> '' and addr2 is not null then addr2 +',' else '' end +
case when addr3<> '' and addr3 is not null then addr3 +',' else '' end +
case when addr4<> '' and addr4 is not null then addr4 +',' else '' end +
zip
```

Use `concat` or a similar function if `+` is not the concatenation operator in ingres.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT CONCAT( CASE WHEN ISNULL(Add1,'') <> '' THEN Add1 + ',' END ,              CASE WHEN ISNULL(Add2,'') <> '' THEN Add2 + ',' END,CASE WHEN ISNULL(Add3,'') <> '' THEN Add3 + ',' END,CASE WHEN ISNULL(Add4,'') <> '' THEN Add4 + ',' END,CASE WHEN ISNULL(postcode,'') <> '' THEN postcode END)